# Tensorflow weight matrix rank error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, convolution

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
cur_dir = os.getcwd()

def modify_image(image):
   resized = tf.image.resize_images(image, 180, 180, 1)
   resized.set_shape([180,180,3])
   flipped_images = tf.image.flip_up_down(resized)
   return flipped_images

def read_image(filename_queue):
   reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
   key,value = reader.read(filename_queue)
   image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(value)
   return key,image

def inputs():
   filenames = ['standard_1.jpg', 'standard_2.jpg' ]
   filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)
   filename,read_input = read_image(filename_queue)
   reshaped_image = modify_image(read_input)
   reshaped_image = tf.cast(reshaped_image, tf.float32)
   label=tf.constant([1])
   return reshaped_image,label

def weight_variable(shape):
 initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
 return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
 initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
 return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
 return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
 return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                    strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')



image,label = inputs()
W_conv1=weight_variable([5,5,3,32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)


W_conv2=weights_variable([5,5,32,64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([32])
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)
W_fc1 = weight_variable([8 * 8 * 32, 512])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([512])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 8*8*32])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
W_fc2 = weight_variable([512, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(y_*tf.log(y_conv))   
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)) 

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
for i in xrange(100):
    img,label = sess.run(image)
    print (label)
    train_step.run({img, label, 0.5})
```

When I run the code, I get the error,

```
"ValueError: ShapesTensorShape([Dimension(180),Dimension(180),Dimension(3)]) and TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None), Dimension(None)]) must have the same rank"
```

But the Weights have been initialized and even then, it shows them as empty tensors.
The files and labels are being read and transfered properly.
The first convolutional layer has a 5x5 window with a depth of 3 and I want to have 32 such 5X5 filters. Hence a shape of [5,5,3,32] for W_conv1.

Answer (score 2):

The `inputs()` function returns a tensor of shape `180 x 180 x 3`, but [`tf.nn.conv2d()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d) expects a 4-D tensor of shape `batch_size x height x width x num_channels`.

[As etarion suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35549196/3574081), you can make this work by reshaping the `image` tensor (e.g. using `image = tf.expand_dims(image, 0)`). However, if you are training a neural network you will probably want to *batch* the inputs. One way to do this is using [`tf.train.batch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch):

```
image, label = inputs()

# Set batch_size to the largest value that works for your configuration.
image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=32)
```

...then use `image_batch` or `label_batch` where you've used `image` and `label` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried using the train.batch() method, but no luck. I have the following doubts, FIRST if train.batch() method  outputs a list of tensors, then why are we assigning it to image_batch and label_batch separately. Why can't we just use image_batch[0 or 1] to access them respectively. SECONDLY, when i pass image_batch and label_batch to their respective placeholders during training, I get the following error  "'Operation' object is not callable"

Comment: 1. Doing `image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch(...)` is equivalent to `batches = tf.train.batch(...); image_batch = batches[0]; label_batch = batches[1]`. 2. I'm not sure what you're doing here to get that error - you might need to make that another question (however, you won't be able to pass `image_batch` or `label_batch` as *feed values* because they are symbolic tensors; only feeding concrete values like NumPy arrays is supported right now. Instead you should use `image_batch` and `label_batch` as the arguments to ops directly, without going via a placeholder).

Comment: I have made a separate question. Could you please check it out ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691099/tensorflow-convolutonal-neural-network-with-custom-data-set  @mrry

Answer (score 0):

It looks like inputs is returning a 3d tensor while conv2d expects a 4d one (first dimension is batch idx) - if you just want to run one image, you'd reshape it to [1,180,180,3] first.