# Tensorflow - Convolutonal neural network with custom data set DOES NOT LEARN

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to make a convolutional neural network for custom data set. The classifier has only two classes. I am able to read the input images properly and have also assigned them the batch_labels for the two corresponding classes . The code executes without error, but the output is anomalous.
For some reason, the accuracy is always 50%.

```
image=inputs()

image_batch=tf.train.batch([image],batch_size=150)
label_batch_pos=tf.train.batch([tf.constant([0,1])],batch_size=75) # label_batch for first class
label_batch_neg=tf.train.batch([tf.constant([1,0])],batch_size=75) # label_batch for second class
label_batch=tf.concat(0,[label_batch_pos,label_batch_neg])

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 3, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

image_4d = tf.reshape(image, [-1,32,32,3])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(image_4d, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([8 * 8 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 8*8*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, 0.5)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 2])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([2])

y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)
cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(label_batch,tf.float32)*tf.log(y_conv+1e-9))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)


tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)
correct_prediction=tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(label_batch,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

for i in range(100):
 train_step.run(session=sess)
 print(sess.run(accuracy))

print(sess.run(correct_prediction))
```

When I print the `correct_prediction` tensor, I get the following output no matter what.

```
[ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True
  True  True  True False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False]
```

The accuracy is always 0.5, as if the weights are not being updated at all. When I print weights after each training step, they remain unchanged. I think I have some coding error.   Could it be that the network is training on the same image again and again? But even so, the weights must update.   I have 150 training examples, with 75 belonging to each class.
Could someone please point me in the right direction ?

**EDIT**:
This is how I initialize weights

```
def weight_variable(shape,name):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.5)
  return tf.Variable(initial,name=name)

def bias_variable(shape,name):
  initial = tf.constant(1.0, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial,name=name)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your network has some design flaws. Because of mathematical issues it is not a good idea to calculate the cross entropy yourself and apply a softmax on the output layer. If you are interested in the mathematics I could add this, if not stick to the Tensorflow explanation and method: [tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits).

Have you already tried many different configurations? Depending on the complexity of your images a higher or lower kernel size and amount of feature maps might be a good idea. Generally, if your images are relatively homogeneous, a lot of rather similar information is added up and therefore the network has it harder to converge if you have many feature maps. Since you have only two output neurons I assume are images are not very complex?

The next thing is your dropout. You are always using a dropout of 0.5 but normally, for test/validation (like your accuracy prediction) you do not use dropout. In most cases you only use it for training. You can create a placeholder specifying your dropout rate and feed this `sess.run`.

Here is some example of my own:

```
h_fc_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc, keep_prob)

(...)

accu, top1, top3, top5 = sess.run([accuracy, te_top1, te_top3, te_top5],
                            feed_dict={
                                x: teX[i: i + batch_size],
                                y: teY[i: i + batch_size]
                                keep_prob: 1.0
                            }
                         )
```

This lets Tensorflow calculate my equations for `accuracy` and `topX` error rate, while I feed in the test data input `teX` and the real labels `teY` for the output with a keep probability `keep_prob` of 1.0 for the dropout.

Despite this the initialization of your weights is really important in deep neural networks. Even if your design is sufficient for your kind of problem (this also has to be investigated) your network could refuse to learn, diverge or converge to 0 if your weights are not initialized properly. You did not add details to your initialization so you maybe want to look up *Xavier initialization*. [This](http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/110998971763/an-explanation-of-xavier-initialization) is an easy beginning for Xavier initialization.

Conclusively I can just encourage you to plot some weights, feature maps, the output over time and so on to get an idea of what your network is doing. Normally this helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks! FIRST, Yes, I would like to know the math behind not using the softmax layer. SECOND, I am not using feed_dict because my inputs have a single batch and they are tensors, not numpy arrays. THIRD, Yes, I tried many configurations but relief. The network refuses to learn no matter what. I believe it is a coding flaw. FOURTH, I tried without any dropout too, but nothing to my relief. FIFTH, I have initialized the weights too, so that there are no dead neurons.

Comment: I have edited the question, to give you a better insight to the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Where and even more important how do you initialize your weights?

Comment: I have edited the question, showing the weight initialization.

Comment: Your init is far too big. How big are your images? For 1000 neurons a stddev of <= 0.1 or even less may be appropriate. Please plot your output, I would assume it to be really high on the last layer so that the softmax does not compute something useful. If the activation is too high your network may diverge and therefore refuse to learn.

Comment: Yeah I believe that could be th problem. I have 32x32x3 images, 75 belonging to each class. I'll try it with smaller initialization and get back to you. If there are any other suggestions let me know. Thanks!! Much Appreciated!!

Comment: For big networks and some problems also a small or even 0 init for bias helps since in combination with relu you generate strong inhibitory feedback with this (guarantees that not too much  classes are activated at the same time).

Comment: Hey! I tried it. The weights are changing now... initialization worked. But the output is as if the network is being trained on a single kind of input. The prediction is same all the time. Thus the accuracy is 0.5 all the time. https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8hRm3BEemiCTHRpMUliaEk0b2M&usp=sharing . Here is the link to entire code. Could you please have a look at it once? Looks like it is training on one image only. Could it be a bug in code?

Comment: Here is a github link. Sorry for the drive link : https://github.com/parhartanvir/Tensor_flow/blob/master/my_tf2.py

Comment: Sorry, no time at the moment - busy until at least wednesday. But you could check this yourself: either plot the input of your network or pause/stop your training after any training step and feed different training images. The first approach shows you directly what's going on while the second proves that your network always classifies for just one class.

Comment: I'll try that. Thanks!!